# which sensor will give out the MultiEchoLaserScan sensor msgs? Which brand and which type?

Tags: ros-kinetic, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The backpack demo_2d  cartographer uses MultiEchoLaserScan Message for Lidar data. I wanna know that which sensor is giving out this kind of data? I want to have this configuration for large area mapping also.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310825/which-sensor-will-give-out-the-multiecholaserscan-sensor-msgs?-which-brand-and-which-type?/) by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) on ROS Answers with karma: 710 on 2018-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hokuyo UTM-30-LX-EW supports multi-echo mode.

Just randomly find out this and reminds me I asked a question here. Hope can help someone who is playing with cartographer and wondering the same thing. Below are the two ref links.

https://acroname.com/blog/hokuyo-laser-range-finder-comparison
https://answers.ros.org/question/199072/how-to-set-single-echo-mode-on-multi-echo-lidar/

---

Originally posted by [tianb03](https://answers.ros.org/users/1587/tianb03/) with karma: 710 on 2020-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0